# cscope like functionality for C++ (using vim)

Tags: vim, cscope

Is there any utility or plugin which provides cscope like functionality for C++. I am looking for

- all references to a symbol
- global definitions
- functions called by a function
- functions calling a function
- files including a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim can interface directly with cscope out of the box.  Type `:h cscope`.  This requires cscope functionality to be enabled when Vim is compiled and for cscope to be installed on your computer.

There is a [Vim + cscope tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) on the cscope web page.

Comment: is there any other tool which can provide similar functionality

Comment: I have found a program called Silent Bob (http://silentbob.sourceforge.net/), but have not tried it.  It claims to support C++, perl and Python.

Answer (score 12):

There are some tools listed in the thread, https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1qktcb/cscope_like_functionality_that_correctly_handles/:

- Clang ctags https://github.com/drothlis/clang-ctags (uses clang to parse, supports C/C++) - seems to generate plain classic "TAGS" file (go to definition only, "level 1" of  Exuberant Ctags) for Emacs and Vi
- Clang tags https://github.com/ffevotte/clang-tags (uses clang to parse, supports C/C++; needs server running to use) - works with [JSON Compilation Database](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html), supports both go to definition [(`clang-tag find-def`)](http://ffevotte.github.io/clang-tags/quickStart.html) / go to usage [(`clang-tag grep`)](http://ffevotte.github.io/clang-tags/quickStart.html). [vim-clang-tags](https://github.com/asenac/vim-clang-tags) can be used to list all usages (`:ClangTagsGrep` command); there is emacs plugin too
- Rtags https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags (named for Roberto Raggi who wrote c++ parser and assured to switch to clang parsing; C/C++ with limited ObjC/ObjC++; server-based with `./bin/rdm` daemon) - has "follow-symbol" and "find-references". Intergates with emacs - `"rtags.el"`; there are two projects for Vim: https://github.com/lyuts/vim-rtags (rich support of rtags) and https://github.com/shaneharper/vim-rtags (only 2 commands) both with "Find references" and "find definition" functions
- bear  https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear (not based on clang, can generate "JSON compilation database" for cmake and non-cmake projects). No any cross-reference functionality?

Some other links

- https://ruben2020.github.io/codequery/ "*CodeQuery is a project that attempts to combine the features available from both cscope and ctags, provide faster database access compared to cscope (because it uses sqlite) and provides a nice GUI tool as well.*", has own gui and vim plugin https://github.com/devjoe/vim-codequery; can't generate cscope database, but its own "CodeQuery sqlite3 db" is converted from cscope.out, generated by pycscope  for python; starscope  for  Ruby, Go and Javascript; original cscope for C and limited C++; can also use TAGS.
- https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery "*cquery is a highly-scalable, low-latency language server for C/C++/Objective-C. It is tested and designed for large code bases like Chromium. cquery provides accurate and fast semantic analysis without interrupting workflow.*" ... finding definition/references, with clang, C/C++; very quick work, fast updates and eats a lot of RAM. Has vim support: https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery/wiki/Vim
- https://www.gnu.org/software/global/ GNU Global is sometimes recommended as cscope replacement. It has "locate not only definitions but also references" and supports " 6 languages by built-in parser. (definition and reference): C, C++, Yacc, Java, PHP4 and assembly." And Vim integration: https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Vim-editor

And there are some fast (indexed) greps like Russ Cox’ codesearch tools (It works with regex too - https://github.com/google/codesearch; example is https://codesearch.debian.net/about) or any other indexed grep...

And there are cross ref tools (GUI and web-servers) like LXR and other... https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/wiki/Comparison-with-Similar-Tools

Comment: Thanks, rtags works perfectly. It is far superior to ctags+cscope, which is almost unusable in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe).

It's got code completion, go-to-definition and refactoring not just for C & C++, but for Rust, Go, Java, C# and more.

Make sure to install it with support for clangd as described [here](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.1/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clangd/Installation.html).